How can I take a radar image mapped to a color gradient, and convert it to a grayscale gradient?
Free software is preferred, if possible. I have some skill with G'MIC, GIMP, and Krita, and am doing my final model in Blender.
I have a radar map of the planet Venus which I, through triplanar texturing techniques, have mapped to a sphere. However, it's still in the original gradient, which I have adequately reproduced as an SVG file.
To use this, I now need to bump-map based on the radar data. I understand why they went with a color gradient, but to use this I need to either be able to interpret based on this gradient, or convert it to a grayscale image. I'm not entirely sure how to do either.
By my best effort, I would be doing a reverse color look-up based on proximity of pixel color to the gradient. I feel like that's something which I shouldn't have to program myself, but I'm not entirely sure how to do it with available tools.

ADDENDUM: I'm currently running a Python script to generate a grayscale image by finding the closest color on the gradient, by Euclidean distance, to each pixel. Unfortunately it's 16K and I think some of my code contains some Numpy abuses, so it's going to be running for quite a while.
Once I know it works, I'm going to Steve McConnell it and get it running efficiently, and then I may present it here. It's a reasonably short script.

Showing the images that you have access to would greatly improve this question

@ZachSaucier A fair point. I had to reduce its size quite a bit (16K original in TIFF format), but this should give everyone an idea of what I'm working with.

Typically the reason it is a tiff is that it has a layer with the data thats actually the distance data. But even if it hasnt this image allmost certainly can be also aquired in that form

@joojaa Unfortunately I'm not finding such a layer; I think it may simply have been used becaust TIFF was like the EXR of 1998. That's a great suggestion though.

Raster image editors have filters which can distill in every pixel hue, saturation and brightness to separate layers or to RGB channels. GIMP does this especially easily:

The original map layer is duplicated and Color > Components > Extract component > Hue is applied to the duplicate. It's dialog offers as an option to invert the scale.
The original is needed to remember where was the actually undefined area i.e. the original black.
My example is made of your noisy attachment, so my "original" contains plenty of JPG compression dirt and numerous black clusters inside the mapped area. In addition the min and max elevations look quite the same in your attachment, which obviously is a fatal error or an intentional move to remove the scientific value from a piece which is sold as art. Hopefully you have also a good "original".

Thank you, yes, I noticed that later. As far as I can tell, the radar is actually closer to white at the extreme highs, not purple, and that whole gradient has been agitating for a number of reasons... they actually do provide the CSV from the probe, but it's 2.9 TB of data, which is its own problem. Thank you for outlining this so clearly.

As an additional note, I've kind of accepted that this presentation of the data is almost useless scientifically. Artifacts aside, we have many "stutters" in the data from Venus's atmosphere alone, and it's going to need to be thoroughly buffed. However, I think that's safe enough for entertainment and education value.

This is a substantial improvement and might be usable, but I am seeing some sharp artifacts like the big bright peak in the north going from sharp black to high intensity white. I'm pretty sure I can scuff that out by hand, though, and it's more a fault of the chosen gradient than your method.
